# React Native Props {children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem where child content passed as props {children} sometimes does not render in my component.

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const Button = ({onPress, children}) => {
    const {buttonStyle, textStyle }  = styles;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle} >
            <Text style={textStyle}> {children} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = {
    textStyle: {
      alignSelf: 'center',
      color: "#fff",
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: '600',
      paddingTop: 10,
      paddingBottom: 10
    },
    buttonStyle:{
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#ff5763',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ff6555',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    }
};

export { Button };
```

When I use this component with props {children} on LoginForm is ok

```
<Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
    Log In
</Button>
```

[image]

But when I want to use in app.js button in empty ;/

```
<Header textHeader={'Authentication'}/>
    <Button>
        Blablabla
    </Button>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your exact question? you just posted the code and screen

Comment: The question is :)

Why when using the Button component with an inscription in app.js - the string is not passed and displayed?

Comment: It looks like the button is there, but your style settings may be making it have no height.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the value is being passed correctly but the button is not rendering correctly. Your Button's style defines no explicit height, instead uses `flex: 1` which is based the parent container.

Check your parent component's style properties to ensure it has a valid height, or add an explicit min-height to the button.